# How to redirect port 80 to 443 in Network Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

```
farwardtotargetgroup:      
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  Properties: 
    Certificates: 
     - CertificateArn: !Ref cert
    DefaultActions: 
      - TargetGroupArn: !Ref target-group
        Type: forward
    LoadBalancerArn: !Ref nlb
    Port: 443 
    Protocol: TLS
redirectto443:      
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  Properties: 
    DefaultActions: 
      - RedirectConfig: 
          Port: 443
          StatusCode: HTTP_301 
        Type: redirect 
    LoadBalancerArn: !Ref nlb
    Port: 80 
    Protocol: TLS
```

When I execute template I got:

The action type 'redirect' is not valid with network load balancer (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidLoadBalancerAction;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redirect rules are only supported for Application Load Balancers, not a network load balancer.

If you can use an application load balancer for your application then you will be able to make use of it.

From [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-listener-defaultactions.html)

> [Application Load Balancer] Information for creating a redirect action. Specify only when Type is redirect.

Comment: Ok. I can't use application. Which rule I use to redirect 80 to 443?

Comment: Hi, a network load balancer does not have redirect rules. It only supports rules to forward all traffic to a target group. You will need to do the redirect in your application instead

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand. Why I can't? How should I do it in application?

Comment: Your web server, or the application itself will need to. The reason why is because a Network Load Balancer is not primarily targeted at web applications it is instead meant for performance. It operations at layer 4, whereas an ALB operates at layer 7. Http operates at layer 7 so only at this layer can it occur

Comment: Thank you. I use TLS now. Maybe TCP can work? It better?

Comment: If you're using TLS, why can't you use ALB whats the usecase?

Comment: Thank  you. I dont decide about ALB. it is network balancer.  Can you write how should I do?

Comment: You will need to do it on your web server (apache, nginx) or in your application. This will vary based on your setup

Comment: Thank you. I check and ask again for more.

Comment: It nodejs. What to do now?

Comment: Hey take a look at: https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/node-js/tutorials/make-https-the-defacto-standard/

Comment: Thank you. I try and ask more.

Comment: Where I put this; app.get("*", function(request, response){
  response.redirect("https://" + request.headers.host + request.url);
}); ??? which file?

Comment: His this would be wherever the routing is in your application code.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know. I deploy. It not my program. Can you explain what to do?

Comment: Hi, this would be with whomever maintains the code base. It'll be specific to your development team

Comment: Thank you. Maybe better redirect on load balancer? Can you find link?

Comment: Hi, Network Load Balancers do not support redirects, it Application Load Balancers that support this

Comment: Hi yes you can add a listener for each port, that works

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/create-listener.html. HTTP would be TCP and port 80

Comment: Thank you. I check and ask more.

Comment: according to https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs, network load balancers support port redirection